# Load testing using a resistor bank

Tags: resistors, dc, safety, heat

I have a bespoke 48V down converter that I'm looking to test which should be able to provide a maximum of 500W of power. I'm looking to test the device under various loads - from 50W to 500W.

I'm trying to do this on a budget - and already have some 4.7ohm 1kW rated chassis mount resistors. Since one resistor will only ever have a maximum of 500W going through it I presume these should be fine (perhaps a fan blowing over their surface to help dissipate heat may help). I will be connecting these resistors in series/parallel to achieve various resistive values to change the load being tested - thinking of using 12AWG cable for this. Max current draw will be approx. 10A so this should be fairly safe?

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should look for and into the datasheet of these resistors.

Comment: As mentioned each resistor is rated for up to 1kW (which leads me to think there would be no issue) - but see below information:

Power rating @70°C in free air 50W – 2500W (see table)
Resistance range See table
Selection series E12
Tolerance ±5% ±10%
Temperature Coefficient of
resistance
<ϮϬΩ ±ϰϬϬPPM/°C
≥ϮϬΩ ±ϯϬϬPPM/°C
Operating temperature range -55 ~ +155°C
Short term overload 3 x rated power / 5 seconds
Dielectric strength 2500VAC Min.
Insulation resistance DCϱϬϬV ϮϬMΩ min.

Comment: The details of the resistor should be added to the post. Also, your test setup should be fine.  Start with short test durations, just in case.

Comment: Don't mount the resistors too close together.

Comment: Derate Pmax at least 1/3 as not to reach max T 125'C consider parallel water cooled power NPN's base controlled for R . Consider high beta or Darlington for pot control or ramp or logic step tests for overshoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One 4,7 Ohm resistor connected to 48 V burns up 490 W.

If you connect two of them in series to 48 V, each one spends 122.5 W and both together 245 W.

10 of these resistors in series result in 49 W and only 4.9 W for each.

For a 490 W load you may use a circuit of 4 resistors, two parallel strings of two resistors in series. Each resistor spends only 122.5 W.

So if you avoid to use a single resistor at 48 V and 10.2 A and 490 W, the resistors spend only a small fraction of the rated 1 kW. You are well below limits and the resistors should not get too hot.

Comment: I use tungsten light bulbs.  I put 8 of them in various sizes in a case with a main switch and a switch for each light so I can switch whatever combination I want.  They are 120V std light bulbs. There is an inrush depending on the voltage and temperature but it works and the price was right. I even have a volt and amp meter in the case.

Comment: @Gil The difference between cold and hot resistance of tungsten lightbulbs is pretty strong.

Comment: That is why i mentioned the inrush. If your voltage is constant the load will remain reasonably constant. The lower the voltage the more stable the resistance, the colder they will be. Nice part simple heat sinking. I built this unit over 40 years ago and it still works great on AC or DC.